# mognodb got signal 2 (Interrupt)

Tags: mongodb, signals, interrupt

```
2017-01-18T03:00:01.404+0800 I CONTROL  [signalProcessingThread] got signal 2 (Interrupt), will terminate after current cmd ends
2017-01-18T03:00:01.404+0800 I FTDC     [signalProcessingThread] Shutting down full-time diagnostic data capture
2017-01-18T03:00:01.409+0800 I REPL     [signalProcessingThread] Stopping replication applier threads
2017-01-18T03:00:02.981+0800 I CONTROL  [signalProcessingThread] now exiting
2017-01-18T03:00:02.981+0800 I NETWORK  [signalProcessingThread] shutdown: going to close listening sockets...
2017-01-18T03:00:02.981+0800 I NETWORK  [signalProcessingThread] closing listening socket: 6
2017-01-18T03:00:02.981+0800 I NETWORK  [signalProcessingThread] closing listening socket: 7
2017-01-18T03:00:02.981+0800 I NETWORK  [signalProcessingThread] closing listening socket: 8
2017-01-18T03:00:02.981+0800 I NETWORK  [signalProcessingThread] removing socket file: /tmp/mongodb-27017.sock
2017-01-18T03:00:02.981+0800 I NETWORK  [signalProcessingThread] shutdown: going to flush diaglog...
2017-01-18T03:00:02.981+0800 I NETWORK  [signalProcessingThread] shutdown: going to close sockets...
2017-01-18T03:00:02.982+0800 I STORAGE  [signalProcessingThread] WiredTigerKVEngine shutting down
2017-01-18T03:00:03.232+0800 I STORAGE  [signalProcessingThread] shutdown: removing fs lock...
2017-01-18T03:00:03.232+0800 I CONTROL  [signalProcessingThread] dbexit:  rc: 0
```

but, we use

```
 processManagement:
    fork: true
```

as this config, can't send a interrupt to mongod via ctrl c ,
and no other admin tools manage mongod.

Is mongo internal thread send a signal to itself?